# Is it SPECIFICALLY mentioned in the Vedas, Agamas, Itihasa or Puranas that left-handed men are inherently evil?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, upanishads, agamas

Scriptures say that our left hand is not to be used for eating, drinking and puja rituals like feeding idols. Some cultures say its bad to eat, drink or do auspicious things by using the left hand. Some take the opposite view.

But I recently heard a child who is a self-proclaimed online Guru claim that he read himself **in the Mahabharata and Bhavishya Purana that left-handed people are inherently evil natured.** He forgot where this is mentioned. Can anyone cite a shloka or translation from any scripture which says something to the effect of:

> Left-handed people are impure and wicked by their very birth... No left-handed man can become a brahmin or rishi... Left-handedness is a brain defect.

Or is it a fabricated myth?

Comment: Are you talking about [Vāmācāra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vamachara) or Vāmamārga and not literally left-handed people?

Comment: I'm talking about literally left-handed people. Some consider them auspicious. But in Islam & Christianity it is said that the devil uses his left hand a lot so we shouldn't use it for eating and auspicious things. There is nothing saying that even if left-handers use their right hand for such things, they are still inherently wicked people. However, I heard Hinduism states such a thing and I was hoping to get a reference

Comment: Yes the right side symbolically "represents" things --- but where does scripture specifically state that literally left-handed born men are inherently wicked or have a brain defect (even if they use their right hand for eating, drinking and feeding idols)?

Comment: Arjuna is often referred to as [savyasaachi](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03080.htm) (literally, "capable of drawing the bow with his left hand"). So it's unlikely the Mahabharata would say something like that.

Comment: It's a baseless superstition. All our deities have two or more arms, and all the left-side arms are equally holding weapons or doing other auspicious things. Dhanalakshmi is showering wealth and coins from her left hand. The four Vyuhas of Vishnu - Vasudeva, Sankarshana, Aniruddha and Pradyumna, symmetrically have swapped positions of the four instruments in their four hands, both left and right.